# Counting the number of combinations when some values are fixed

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

> A reading list for a humanities course consists of 10 books; of which
>   4 are biographies and the rest are novels. Each student is required to
>   read a selection of 4 books from the list including 2 or more
>   biographies. How many selections of 4 books satisfy the requirements?
>   (source: New Revised GRE General Guide)

I initially tried to solve the problem by doing: $\binom{4}{2} \binom{8}{2}$ (i.e., (4 choose 2) * (8 choose 2)). That gives me 168.

However, the answer is actually 115. I understand how the answer solved it:
look at 3 cases:

- Case 1: 2 bios and 2 fiction
- Case 2: 3 bios and 1 fiction
- Case 3: 4 bios and 0 fiction

And add up the number of combinations of each.

But what's wrong with my approach?

Comment: Welcome to MSE =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach counts a selection more than once if it contains more than two biographies. Then your formula wants to decide exactly which of the two biographies *the* biographies and the third (and possibly fourth) is considered merely an honorary novel.

For example, with biographies BA, BB, BC, BD and novels N1 through N6, your formula counts

- {BA,BB}+{BD,N3}
- {BA,BD}+{BB,N3}
- {BB,BD}+{BA,N3}

as different selections even though they lead to exactly the same reading.

Comment: Perhaps one should add that the correct approach is to say "4 choose 2" then "6 choose 2" + "4 choose 3" then "6 choose 1" + "4 choose 4" then "6 choose 0" which leads to 
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 6 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 6 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 6 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = 115
$$.

Comment: @Patrick, that appears to be implicit it in the part of the question beginning "I understand how the answer solved it".

Comment: Great! Excellent answer, your example (with the BA, BB, etc and N1 to N6) helped me see where I was double counting. Thank you so much!